# Probability measure preserving action on a countable space has finite orbits

Tags: probability, group-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, group-actions

I need a reference to the statement:

Let $G$ be a countable group acting on $(E,\mu)$ a probability space where $\mu$ is measure preserving. Suppose further that $E$ is countable. Then the orbits of the action of $G$ are finite.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the sigma algebra on $(E, \mu)$? Is it discrete, i.e. is every singleton set $\{x\} \subseteq E$ measurable?

Comment: @jflipp Borel, so yes every singleton is measurable

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the group action is a homomorphism from the group to measure preserving bijections on $E$. I don't have a reference but I could think of the following argument when the measure $\mu$ has full support: Since $\mu$ has full support, $\mu(\{e\})>0$ for all $e \in E$. Assume the orbit of some $e \in E$ is countable. Thus, there must exist countably many distinct points $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset E $ such that $g \cdot e=e_n$ for some $g \in G$ and $\mu(\{e_n\})= \mu(g^{-1}\{e_n\})=\mu(\{e\})>0$. Thus we have that $\mu(E)\geq \mu(\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})=+\infty$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: On the other hand if $\mu$ is not fully supported, I think there is a counterexample: Consider $(E,\mu)=(\mathbb{Z},\delta_0)$, where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac mass at $0$. Consider the countable group $G$ generated by the map $g:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, $g(0)=0$, $g(-1)=1$, and $g(n)=n+1, n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0,-1\}$. It is a subgroup of the automorphism group of $(\mathbb{Z},\delta_0)$, i.e. $g^{n}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a measure preserving bijection. Consider its canonical action on $(\mathbb{Z},\delta_0)$. Then, for example, the orbit of $n=1$ is all integers excluding $0$.

Comment: This is not really my field, I would be happy for anyone to correct me.